# How to fix "Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `...` is unknown". Using pipes, group_by & summarize in functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to show the number of observations(rows) for each value of a grouping variable in my df and put this into a function for later use.

I don´t understand why the function version of the code does not work, while the non-function version works fine. Help would be very much appreciated.

library(dplyr)

## Version without function

```
mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>%  summarize(noOfObs = length(am))
```

## Version with function

```
noOfObsByGroup <- function(df, group) {
  df %>% group_by(group) %>%  summarize(noOfObs = length(group))
}
noOfObsByGroup(mtcars, am)
```

The function version throws the error "Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `group` is unknown".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint! The discussion in this programming chapter of dplyr is what I needed.